# semi-advanced MYSQL query

Tags: mysql, sql-update, row, multiple-instances

Let's say I have table 'items'.
There are 500 rows in table 'items'.
I want to add a new column, 'new'.
Rows 1 - 100 need to have 'A' in column 'new',
Rows 101 - 200 need to have 'B' in column 'new',
Rows 201 - 300 need to have 'C' in column 'new'.
Etc, etc.

so:

Is there a mysql query to do something like:

```
UPDATE items WHERE rows 1 THROUGH 100 (UPDATE 'A' IN new)
```

Comment: By what attribute do you order your rows?

Comment: Or is this there a way to add the 'Checked' Rows to a mysql query?

Comment: How do you know which row is `row 1`?

Comment: A primary key was assigned. Problem solved below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

For 1-100

```
    UPDATE table
    set new = 'A'
    where id in 
    (
     Select temp.Id from
     ( 
       Select id as Id from table limit 1,100
      ) as temp
   )
```

For 101-200

```
    UPDATE table
    set new = 'B'
    where id in 
    (
     Select temp.Id from
     ( 
       Select id as Id from table limit 101,100
      ) as temp
   )
```

Comment: How does this put different values in rows '201-300', '301-400', etc?

Comment: I see. But where do I tell it that the values are going in column 'new'?

Comment: I'm getting an error:   
"#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'items limit 32,40) as temp)' at line 4"

Comment: Show me your query, seems like you are changing something

Comment: (For testing I'm only trying rows 32 through 40)

Comment: UPDATE items
set  new = 'A'
where id in 
(Select temp.Id from (Select id as Idfrom items limit 32,40) as temp)

Comment: sorry I missed a space in my subquery have edited, kindly check

Comment: now I'm getting this error: #1054 - Unknown column 'id' in 'field list' - -    should 'id' be 'new'?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39425/discussion-between-sashi-kant-and-ghost-echo)

Comment: with a few variables swaps this is just what I need!

Comment: Good that it was helpful